# List of network peers in Parity

Tags: parity, peers

I'm exploring option to add parity peers, however my my peers are in a different networks. Should I still use internal IPs that are visible when starting a parity?

I've loaded reserved peers and used `parity_netPeers` method to pull list of connected peers. Nodes from the list are there, however protocol field is `null` both for `eth` and `pip`, which means that they are not connected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think they are not connected?

Comment: Turned out that I had to whitelist and redirect traffic on ports 30303. It's weird to me as parity was working fine without whitelisting, so I just assumed it works like P2P over NAT.